# How can I implement it using switch case?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I have the following function:

```
gameActions(e: KeyboardEvent) {
        if (e.keyCode === 27 || e.keyCode === 9 || (e.keyCode === 9 && e.shiftKey)) { 
            this.LaunchInventory();
        }
        else if (e.keyCode === 13) { //Enter
            this.Shoot();
        }
        else if (e.keyCode === 40) { //Down
            this.Crouch();
        }
        else if (e.keyCode === 38) { //Up
            this.Jump();
        }
    }
```

How can I implement this code using switch case? I am just unable to figure out how to pass the conditional statement `e.shiftKey && e.keyCode` to the case statement.

Comment: This doesn’t look like JavaScript. Anyway, show us what you’ve tried.

Comment: The first `if` statement is not dependent on `e.shiftKey`. `if (e.keyCode === 27 || e.keyCode === 9)` is sufficient.

Comment: Just a tip: Your final conditional for LaunchInventory() is redundant. If `(e.keyCode === 9 && e.shiftKey)` is true, then just `e.keyCode === 9` is also true.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `e.keyCode === 9 && e.shiftKey` condition is completely redundant, as checking for `e.keyCode === 9` would suffice to enter the same condition. You could just drop it, which would make using a switch-case quite straight forward:

```
gameActions(e: KeyboardEvent) {
    switch(e.keycode) {
        case 27:
        case 9:
            this.LaunchInventory();
            break;
        case 13:
            this.Shoot();
            break;
        case 40:
            this.Crouch();
            break;
        case 38:
            this.Jump();
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I completely overlooked it. Feels so dumb!